# PHP clean unclickable url but keep img

Tags: php, regex

how can i clean all url from description that are not inside  tag.
and also to keep all img url ?

for example the outcomming result should be like that:

description before:

```
this is my description www.url.com and other stuff. 
i have a picture <img src="www.url.com"> and other desc stuf..
sample text goes here and here..
```

description after should be:

```
this is my description and other stuff. 
i have a picture <img src="www.url.com"> and other desc stuf..
sample text goes here and here..
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have control over the input (ie.do you know what the url looks like)?
And what have you tried so far?

Comment: the url can vary, it can be what ever legible url.

Comment: Anyone who looks at the source can still see the img urls.

Comment: @ScottS That isn't the problem here

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = 'this is my description www.url.com and url.com and http://www.url.com other stuff. 
i have a picture <img src="www.url.com"> and other desc stuf..
sample text goes here and here..';

echo preg_replace('/[^\"](http(s?):\/\/)?(www)?\.?([A-Za-z0-9\-]){2,25}\.(com|net|org)[^\"]/', ' ', $string);
```

OUTPUT:

```
this is my description and and other stuff. 
i have a picture <img src="www.url.com"> and other desc stuf..
sample text goes here and here..
```

Not sure if this is what you're looking for.

It obviously doesn't match every URL possible, but it's somewhere you can start.

Comment: but what about <img src=www.url.com> or <a href="url.com">url.com</a>?

Answer (score 0):

```
$words = explode(' ', $description);
foreach ($words as $k => $v)
    if (filter_var($v, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) || preg_match("/([a-z0-9\.]+)\.([a-z0-9][a-z0-9]+)/i", $v))
        unset($words[$k]);
$description = implode(' ', $words);
```

This solution removes well-formed URLs and domains but it's an approximate solution because I can't know (imho) if a word is a domain like *whereis.it* or a simple word like *will.i.am*.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is extremely difficult and you might best try other options. An URL comes in a lot of different shapes and forms and to make a regexp that is 100% reliable for all kinds of urls is pretty hard.

First you have to make a choice if you need to match 100% of the url's or that x% is also good enough and if false positives are ok.

Then you could match all words with a dot, run that through parse_url and if that gives you a good result, remove it from the text.

Comment: Ok, so myabe regexpression is not the solution.  maybe to parse the text manualy from the www or http to the end of the link and check if it is not end wit han image, so remove the url..